# How to add_row in datasummary if the rows don't have the same length as t he original table?

Tags: r, modelsummary

I want to add row to a datasummary object. However, this row has less columns than the original object. This gives an error. How can I add a row that spans multiple  columns?

```
Error in factory(dse, align = align, fmt = fmt, hrule = NULL, notes = notes,  : 
  Assertion on 'add_rows' failed: Must have exactly 5 cols, but has 2 cols.
```

This is the part that works:

```
library(modelsummary)
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
data <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)
summary_table <- datasummary(
  x1 + x2 + y ~ Mean + SD + Min + Max,
  data = data
)

new_row <- data.frame(
  First_variable = "New Row",
  Mean = 1,
  SD = 2,
  Min = 3,
  Max = 4
)

datasummary(
  x1 + x2 + y ~ Mean + SD + Min + Max,
  data = data, add_rows = new_row
)
```

This is the part that does not work:

```
new_row2 <- data.frame(
  First_variable = "New Row",
  Mean = "a bit of a longer text"
)

datasummary(
  x1 + x2 + y ~ Mean + SD + Min + Max,
  data = data, add_rows = new_row2
)
```

Comment: `modelsummary` does not provide for this out of the box, because not all the backend table-drawing packages (ex: kableExtra) support rows with cells that span multiple columns. One approach might be to export your summary statistics with `output="data.frame"`, and to feed that to a table-making package which allows for multi-column cells.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you want a new variable with less data (without min or max) or just want add a new row with some text on that.

The are two examples here

```
 new_row2 <- data.frame(
    First_variable = "New Row",
    Mean = "a bit of a longer text",
    SD = "with some data",
    Min = "in this country",
    Max = "example text bla bla"
  )

datasummary(
  x1 + x2 + y ~ Mean + SD + Min + Max,
  data = data, add_rows = new_row2, align = "lcccc", notes = "New Variable: Text here"
)



new_row2 <- data.frame(
    First_variable = "e",
    Mean = 100,
    SD = "",
    Min = "",
    Max = ""
  )

datasummary(
  x1 + x2 + y ~ Mean + SD + Min + Max,
  data = data, add_rows = new_row2, align = "lcccc"
)
```

In conclusion, you must add a "blank" data in new row

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is somewhere in between. In your first solution, the table gets stretched because of the longer text. basically, I want this: `new_row2 <- data.frame(
  First_variable = "e",
  Mean = "New Row a bit of a longer text with some data",
  SD = "",
  Min = "",
  Max = ""
)

datasummary(
  x1 + x2 + y ~ Mean + SD + Min + Max,
  data = data, add_rows = new_row2, align = "lcccc"
)`
but I want it to use the other cells as well (SD, Min, Max)